# Is it possible to grant users sftp access without shell access? If yes, how is it implemented?

Tags: sftp

I have an array of users who need to just upload files to their set homedirs. I think sftp would suffice, but I don't want them to login via shell. So is it possible?
My platform is centos 7, user's homedirs are stored lets say /personal/$user

I created user with these settings

```
useradd -m -d /personal/user1 -s /sbin/nologin
```

assigned user a passwd, then when I use sftp to login to the machine, it says cannot connect.

Comment: scponly https://github.com/scponly/scponly/wiki chroot optional

Comment: duplicate of https://serverfault.com/questions/354615/allow-sftp-but-disallow-ssh

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Edit your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to contain:

```
Match User [SFTP user]
ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

Restart `sshd`. If you have multiple users put them all on the match user line separated by commas like so:

```
Match User User1,User2,User3
```

The key to configuring `sftp` to not allow shell access is to limit users via the `ForceCommand`  option.

Comment: Ok I did follow all steps but it did not log in

Comment: @Sollosa Try with `Match User [SFTP user]` `ForceCommand internal-sftp` only, without chrooting stuff.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl it worked Martin, thanks, I just removed chrootdirectory parameter & viola

Comment: On top of that, you can `chroot` the users so they can't navigate up and out of your defined "jail"

Answer (score 53):

### Group-based secure-by-default SSH setup

I like the following setup for managing SSH access, which I've used to manage a group of users on small fleets of servers. Security and ease of management is high on the list of my priorities.

Its key features are easily managing SSH rights through Unix group membership, having tightly defined permissions, and being secure by default.

### Setting up

Install software (optional but useful):

```
yum install members   # or apt install members
```

Add groups:

```
addgroup --system allowssh
addgroup --system sftponly
```

Add a new file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/strict.conf` (you can replace `strict` with a better name), with the following contents:

```
PermitRootLogin no
PubkeyAuthentication no
PasswordAuthentication no

Match Group allowssh
    PubkeyAuthentication yes

Match Group sftponly
    ChrootDirectory %h
    DisableForwarding yes
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

This assumes that your OpenSSH setup includes `sshd_config.d/*.conf` to override the main config. Check your SSH documentation, or verify that the main `sshd_config` has an appropriate `Include` directive. If your setup does not support this, you could edit `sshd_config` directly instead.

Also, don't forget to restart the SSH service after modifying the configuration.

### Rationale

So, what does all this do?

- It always disables root logins, as an extra security measure.
- It always disables password-based logins (weak passwords are a big risk for servers running sshd).
- It only allows (pubkey) login for users in the `allowssh` group.
- Users in the `sftponly` group cannot get a shell over SSH, only SFTP.

Managing who has access is then simply done by managing group membership (group membership changes take effect immediately, no SSH restart required; but note that existing sessions are not affected). `members allowssh` will show all users that are allowed to log in over SSH, and `members sftponly` will show all users that are limited to SFTP.

```
# adduser marcelm allowssh
# members allowssh
marcelm
# deluser marcelm allowssh
# members allowssh
#
```

Note that your sftp users need to be members of both `sftponly` (to ensure they won't get a shell), and of `allowssh` (to allow login in the first place).

### Further information

1. Please note that this configuration **does not allow password logins**; all accounts *need* to use public key authentication. This is probably the single biggest security win you can get with SSH, so I argue it's worth the effort even if you have to start now.

   If you really don't want this, then also add `PasswordAuthentication yes` to the `Match Group allowssh` stanza. This will allow both pubkey and password auth for `allowssh` users. Alternatively, you can add another group (and `Match Group` stanza) to selectively grant users password-based logins.
2. This configuration limits any `sftponly` user to their home directory. If you do not want that, remove the `ChrootDirectory %h` directive.

   If you *do* want the chrooting to work, it's important that the user's home directory (and any directory above it) is owned by `root:root` and not writable by group/other. It's OK for subdirectories of the home directory to be user-owned and/or writable.

   Yes, the user's **home directory must be root-owned** and unwritable to the user. Sadly, there are [good reasons](http://lists.mindrot.org/pipermail/openssh-unix-dev/2009-May/027651.html) for this limitation. Depending on your situation, `ChrootDirectory /home` might be a good alternative.
3. Setting the shell of the `sftponly` users to `/sbin/nologin` is neither necessary nor harmful for this solution, because SSH's `ForceCommand internal-sftp` overrides the user's shell.

   Using `/sbin/nologin` may be helpful to stop them logging in via other ways (physical console, samba, etc) though, so it's still recommended.
4. This setup does not allow direct `root` logins over SSH; this forms an extra layer of security. If you really *do* need direct root logins, change the `PermitRootLogin` directive to `forced-commands-only`, to allow only key-based forced commands through `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys`. As a last resort, you can use `prohibit-password` to allow full key-based logins. Avoid `yes`.
5. For bonus points, have a look at restricting who can `su` to root; add a system group called `wheel`, and add/enable `auth required pam_wheel.so` in `/etc/pam.d/su`.

Comment: Maybe some inexperienced users would be better off testing their configuration reloading the sshd configuration, instead of restarting it!

Comment: Consider also using the `Match Address`  directive, to grant different access levels (like allow ssh only from internal IPs, etc)

Answer (score 1):

just change their default shell to /sbin/nologin. Assuming most varieties of Linux:

```
# usermod -s /sbin/nologin username
```

Comment: I have tried it, but user is not able to login via sftp, I don't know why. I'm using centos btw.

Comment: @Sollosa Probably either a permission problem in your sftp chroot, or sshd_config has a problem. You should update your question to include the permissions of your chroot directory, and your sshd_config with any sensitive information redacted.

Comment: I believe (though I cannot test it now) that this allows SFTP only if there's also `Subsystem sftp internal-sftp`) (or maybe `ForceCommand internal-sftp`). If there's common `Subsystem sftp /path/to/sftp-server`, `nologin` will prevent even SFTP.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I misunderstood their original unedited question to be asking how to disable shell access for users on an otherwise functional sftp server. I'd been awake for about ten minutes at the time so I wasn't as clearheaded as I might have felt. Though I didn't know that sftp-server requires a user to have a valid shell to work - that seems potentially dangerous. I only ever use internal-sftp just out of habit because that's how I've always done it.

Comment: See my answer to [OpenSSH: Difference between internal-sftp and sftp-server](https://serverfault.com/q/660160/168875) (particularly the section at the end)

Answer (score 0):

you can use tftp.
anything over ssh will require a some auth (key|pass).

while tftp can be secured, it may be worth revisiting the decision to provide access to anything without authentication.

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/tftp.1.html

Comment: I think OP wanted users (who presumably have usernames and passwords) to not be able to use a regular SSH client to connect to the server and execute arbitrary commands, but those same users be able to upload files via SFTP.

Comment: `tftp` also has significant issues from a security standpoint. It might be tolerable on a locked-down, well-monitored network but I would not recommend using it for any situation where there's a secure alternative.

Answer (score 0):

There is [`mysecureshell`](https://mysecureshell.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) which allows to restrict users to SFTP and even limit which paths are accessible.

Also there is [`rrsync`](https://download.samba.org/pub/rsync/rrsync.1) for limiting users to `rsync` only.